# Finding extremas when function has no critical points

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to investigate the monotonicity and find extremas of a function $y=\frac{1}{e^x-1}$. However, the function has no critical points. How do I investigate the monotonicitz and find extremas (the function has a minimum) without critical points?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the function has no minumum. Simply compute its derivative and you will see that it is strictly decreasing on $(-\infty,0)$ and also on $(0,\infty)$.